# Regex: How to capture all iterations in repeated capturing group

Tags: c#, .net, regex, capturing-group

I would expect these lines of C#:

```
var regex = new Regex("A(bC*)*");
var match = regex.Match("AbCCbbCbCCCCbbb");
var groups = match.Groups;
```

to return something like:

```
["AbCCbbCbCCCCbbb", "A", "bCC", "b", "bC", "bCCC", "b", "b", "b"]
```

but instead it returns only the last captured match:

```
["AbCCbbCbCCCCbbb", "b"]
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/ZtYa1O/2) Regex101 also displays the following as a warning:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

How should I change my regex pattern?

Comment: Regex101 does not support .NET regex flavor.

Comment: *Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations*

Comment: @Groo I did, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to also capture `A`, just wrap it with parentheses: `new Regex("(A)(bC*)*")`. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(A)(bC*)*&i=AbCCbbCbCCCCbbb).

[image]

Then, collect all the values you have got inside [*CaptureCollection*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var regex = new Regex("(A)(bC*)*");
var match = regex.Matches("AbCCbbCbCCCCbbb")
     .Cast<Match>()
     .SelectMany(x => x.Groups.Cast<Group>()
          .SelectMany(v => v.Captures
              .Cast<Capture>()
              .Select(t => t.Value)
          )
     )
     .ToList();
 foreach (var s in match)
     Console.WriteLine(s);
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/xDOuM0)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
A|b(C+)?
```

Tested in `Notepad++`

Edit: If you want this pattern with groups:

```
(A)|(b(C+)?)
```

Comment: It works in regex101 with javascript flavor, and notepad++ but it doesn't work in Visual Studio, C#. It returns {"A", "A", "", ""}

Comment: Note: This is a completely different pattern. For example, the pattern would match against "bCCbbCbCCCCbbb" while the OG's regex would not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Methinks it's rather do not use .NET if you need a decent regex parser. You do know that apart from some language specific extensions (none are in use here), the capture behavior of a regex is standardized and works the same everywhere. If it does not work that way in .NET, then it's simply broken. Capturing is not a part of "flavor", languages cannot choose freely on this aspect. They can extend the standards but for what the questioner wants to do, no extension is required).